# Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set' when trying to edit Parse object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

When I try to run the following background job, I get an error stating `Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'set'`, referring to the line where I attempt to set the 'Number' property of the object being returned to a value of `2`. I've used this same format to edit Parse objects before, and it worked fine, what am I doing wrong here?

```
 Parse.Cloud.job("sendLowPush", function(request, status) {

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
       /////////////
       //send push notification to all users in the "lowPush" channel 

      //{Query the # value of pushIncrement with object id hKj2Eazz6h}
      var pushIncrement = Parse.Object.extend("pushIncrement");
      var pushIncrementQuery = new Parse.Query(pushIncrement);
      pushIncrementQuery.equalTo('objectId', 'hKj2Eazz6h');


      pushIncrementQuery.find({
        success: function(results) {

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
            var dayNumber = results[i].get("Number");
          }
           console.log('dem results be:' + dayNumber);


           //Figure out whether its day 1, 2, or 3, and increment. Send lowPush if day 3.
          if (dayNumber = 1){
            //change it to 2
            console.log('dayNumber is 1');

            results.set('Number', '2');
            results.save();
          }
          else if (dayNumber = 2){
            //change it to 3
            console.log('dayNumber is 2');
          }

          status.success("Push Notifications completed successfully.");
        },

        error: function(error) {
           console.log('shit');
           status.error('shitty shit');
        }

      });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is the list of objects. You can't set the `Number` field on the whole list. However, it looks like you are only querying for a single object with a specific ID. In that case you should use `.get` instead:

```
pushIncrementQuery.get('hKj2Eazz6h', {
    success: function(obj) {
        var dayNumber = obj.get("Number");
        // ...
        obj.set('Number', '2');
        obj.save();
    }
});
```

If you want to use `.find`, you'd have to access the correct element in the list, i.e. either `results[i]` or `results[0]`.